# Using git pull to track a remote branch without merging

Tags: git, git-pull

I am using git to track content which is changed by some people and shared "read-only" with others.  The "readers" may from time to time need to make a change, but mostly they will not.

I want to allow for the git "writers" to rebase pushed branches** if need be, and ensure that the "readers" never accidentally get a merge.  That's normally easy enough.

```
git pull origin +master
```

There's one case that seems to cause problems.  If a reader makes a local change, the command above will *merge*.  I want pull to be fully automatic if the reader has not made local changes, while if they have made local changes, it should stop and ask for input.  I want to track any upstream changes while being careful about merging downstream changes.

In a way, I don't really want to pull. I want to track the master branch exactly.

---

** (I know this is not a best practice, but it seems necessary in our case: we have one main branch that contains most of the work and some topic branches for specific customers with minor changes that need to be isolated.  It seems easiest to frequently rebase to keep the topics up to date.)

Comment: What would the user do with their modifications?  Commit them to a local branch?

Comment: With Git 2.0, you can try (soon) `git config push.ff only`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22354592/6309)

Answer (score 7):

Your are looking for the command `git-fetch`.

Comment: I'm afraid not.  git-fetch updates the local copy of the branch remotes/origin/master, but it does not update the master branch itself.  I want the "readers" to be able to get a copy of the changes made upstream.

Answer (score 6):

You might also find `git pull --rebase` useful.

**Update:** `--rebase` can be made the default `pull` behavior by setting `branch.<name>.rebase = true` on individual branches. Setting `branch.autosetuprebase = true` will set this on new branches by default, though existing branches would need to be updated manually. Or you can always default to `--rebase` by setting `pull.rebase = true` globally.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
  git pull --ff-only origin master
```

I use that often. Unfortunately, as richard-hansen@ pointed out below, this does not work as an alias:

```
[alias]
pull = pull --ff-only
```

Comment: Unfortunately the alias won't work.  From `git help config`:  "To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing git commands are ignored."

Comment: @RichardHansen did you find a solution for this, or is this just impossible to configure?

Comment: @AndyHayden: Starting with Git 2.0 you can do `git config --global pull.ff only` to cause `git pull` to act like `git pull --ff-only`.

Comment: @RichardHansen nice! Worth noting if you were using rebase=True you need to remove that entry (as it takes precedence)!

Comment: That 2.0 config is interesting, but not helpful to me. I want to decide when I want `--ff-only`, so I use a **bash** alias instead of a **git** alias.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want the manual merging by the readers fetching, you could write a hook to examine what came down and prompt the user:

http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

I would still just recommend fetching and having the readers manage their merges or rebases locally. That's a simpler solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.0 (Q2 2014) will add in [commit b814da8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b814da891e8261b909fc5d9fb07b4e8b13989c2d) a config `push.ff`:

```
pull.ff::
```

> By default, Git does not create an extra merge commit when merging a commit that is a descendant of the current commit. Instead, the tip of the current branch is fast-forwarded.
>
> - When set to false, this variable tells Git to create an extra merge commit in such a case (equivalent to giving the --no-ff option from the command line).
> - **When set to only, only such fast-forward merges are allowed (equivalent to giving the `--ff-only` option from the command line).**

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a workflow using two branches. A merged local branch (master), and a remote 'read-only' tracking branch (remote).

Using dual remotes on a master branch allows you to continue working, and keep up to date with the remote project. Your local changes, and merged remote changes can be pushed to your local git server.

```
 git push localserver master
```

Upstream patches can be created and refined on your remote tracking branches, and submitted to the project.

A separate tracking branch for the 'read-only' remote lets you prepare patches and commits for upstream to the remote project.

```
# Master branch is merge of local changes, and remote changes
git checkout master
git pull -m origin master
# Set up a local tracking branch for the 'read-only' remote.
git checkout -b remote remote master
# Start reviewing changes between the two branches.
git diff --name-status ..master
```

When you want to upstream a patch, a diff from master..remote can be used to define the patch your read-only remote branch.

```
git diff master..remote -- files >patch
git checkout remote
patch -p1 <patch
git commit -m "Your patch"
git format-patch -1
```

Send the formatted patch file to the remote project. If you need to amend and rebase for the remote project, you can do that work on your remote tracking branch until it's approved.

(Setting up a git dual remote involves editing .git/config, and is explained elsewhere)